# Remove mysterious ref from Git

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-filter-branch

After a `filter-branch` and prune/gc, there are still some undesired commits.

They aren't on the branches I care about; there must be some tags or something holding onto them.

I'm trying to figure out what that is, and remove it.

But nothing I try seems to work.

```
$ git name-rev 1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f #what's holding on?
1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80~1320^2~8^2~1
$ git rm -r refs/original
$ git name-rev 1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f
1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80~1320^2~8^2~1
$ git update-ref -d original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80
$ git name-rev 1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f
1bdac1e1ad7ec61a4b05d3f91eb39bde61a4da1f original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80~1320^2~8^2~1
```

(This is in a bare repo.)

How do I remove `original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80`, whatever that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full name is `refs/original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80` and it lives in the `refs/original` name space.  You were very close with this command:

```
git update-ref -d original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80
```

except that `update-ref` requires that you spell out the full name, `refs/original/refs/tags/1.0-rc80`.

You may have some additional `refs/original/*` names since `git filter-branch` copies any ref names there before changing them.  You can see them all with:

```
git for-each-ref refs/original
```

(and you can even use `for-each-ref` to generate commands to remove them, or you can just `rm -rf .git/refs/original` and edit `.git/packed-refs` directly, but the `for-each-ref` method is more likely to work in the future if/when refs are packed differently or something, plus you mentioned that this is a bare repo so they're not in `.git` here...).

Comment: Excellent. Somewhere I read that I could just remove the `refs/original` directory. But clearly `update-ref -d` does something more than that.

Comment: `update-ref` removes the entry from the "packed" refs file too.  Right after `filter-branch` the ref won't have been packed, but once a `gc` runs, some (really, "all") refs wind up in the packed-refs file.